# UIImage with Gradient iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, linear-gradients, cagradientlayer

Is it possible apply a gradient like this for iOS?

[image]

The gradient is applied to the image and it should lose focus. I can get the result for the background with CAGradientLayer but the image always has the same focus.

Comment: you get a solution on this? I tried with CAGradient,Its not working for me.Any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find useful applying some technics for image resizing in order to achieve the focus you want.
http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/